# HTTP Message Body is not Received

Tags: http, sockets, client-server

I'm facing a really strange problem on one of my company's customers site.
Our system tries to send HTTP requests to one of our servers in the site.
The server is running on a machine that runs from within a DMZ.

The client is in Java and the server is C#.
My code sends an HTTP request in the following manner:

[Edit - changed from pseudo to actual code]:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
socket.connect([server address], timeout);

SocketOutputBuffer output = new SocketOutputBuffer (socket);

byte[] buffer = [creating the HTTP request headers]
output.write(buffer);
output.flush();

buffer = [creating the message body]
output.write(buffer);
output.flush();
```

When debugging the client application, the last "output.flush()" finish successfully.
On the server side I see that only the HTTP headers were received on the server side.

The weird thing is that if I close the socket after the last flush the message body arrives to the server.

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hard to diagnose without seeing your actual code.  Since you know the first flush works, have you tried omitting it and flushing only after the message body?

Comment: I've updated the code and I'll try omitting the first flush. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Java? What platform? Do you close the socket after this? Have you shutdown the socket properly? 
In many cases, you must set the socket to shutdown in a manner that allows it to complete sending buffered data (flushing is not guaranteed...)

Comment: The client side runs on an Android device (2.1). What does it mean "set the socket to shutdown"? do you mean closing the socket? My connection is streaming data to the server so I need it to be open through the entire session.
Thanks for replying.

Comment: @LiorOhana: O'Rooney is referring to the socket's linger options, which dictate how the socket behaves in regards to when outbound data is still pending when closing the socket.  By default, a socket continues sending data in the background for a period of time, even though the application handle to the socket has been invalidated from further use.

Comment: @Remy: Just to make sure I understand, do you mean that it might be that for some reason my connection has became invalid and that's why the flush might not work? 10x

Comment: @LiorOhana: no, that is not what I said.  When I said "invalidated", I was referring to when your code closes the connection when you are done with it.  The underlying socket is no longer valid from your app's perspective, but it may still be doing background work before the OS invalidates it completely.  If you really want to know what's going on, try using a packet sniffer to watch the network traffic, make sure calling flush() after sending headers is not closing the connection prematurely.

Comment: @Remy: My problem is not buffered data which is not sent after the socket is closed.
I need to keep my connection open for the entire session.
After each write I call flush but I can't see anything on the server (using a sniffer).

Comment: @LiorOhana: The purpose of using a sniffer (a network sniffer, like Wireshark, not an HTTP sniffer, like Fiddler) is to see if the connection is being closed when `flush()` is called.

Comment: @Remy: OK, I'll check that even though...10x. In anyway, I start to believe that it is related to the internet provide of our customer. With small bit-rates every works fine.